# can't connect on mongodb in docker on windows 10

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

This is my docker-compose.yml setting for MongoDB

```
 image: mongo:latest
 container_name: 'mongodb'
 ports:+
   - 27018:27017
 restart: always
```

It works great on mac but keeps failing to connect on win10 on port `0.0.0.0:27018`

Comment: maybe this port bloked on win10

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is IPv4 for "everywhere"; you don't usually make outbound connections to that address.  Are you running Docker Toolbox or the Docker Desktop application?  That matters too.

Comment: we are running docker desktop app on windows, same on mac OS

Comment: Can you try connecting directly to the container on port 27017 and see if that works? Make sure the container itself is okay first. docker inspect <container> to get its ip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's recommended to present the port configuration in quotes to avoid erroneous after effects.
Reference -> https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/

This can work

```
image: mongo:latest
 container_name: 'mongodb'
 ports:+
   - "27018:27017"
 restart: always
```